# writing a condition in template match in xslt

Tags: xslt

Implementing a condition in template match

```
       <xsl:template match="a[!(img)and(not(@id))]">
```

I want to write a template such that `a` tag should not have attribute `id` and should not be followed by `img` tag.

But its showing error.
Can any one help?

Comment: Did you even read my response to your previous question, where I pointed out your incorrect terminology by referring to tags rather than elements? There are plenty of people on this forum willing to help you advance your knowledge of XSLT, but it's discouraging if the advice isn't heeded.

Comment: Also, a general tip: whenever you ask a question and say that something is failing, or is reporting an error, tell us what the error message is. It might mean nothing to you (perhaps because you haven't yet mastered the correct terminology), but you can be sure it's meaningful to other people.

Comment: @MichaelKay. Sorry for the wrong terminology. I will improve it. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `followed by img tag` refers to children and not siblings, you only have to consolidate your use of the `not()` function, instead of the unsupported `!` operator:

```
<xsl:template match="a[not(img) and not(@id)]">
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I just tried to do something similar, but I'm getting an error. The match I'm doing is as follows: <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'value') and not(ends-with(local-name(), '_p')]">. The error I'm getting is: XTSE0340: The pattern 'not(ends-with(local-name(), '_p')]' specified by the 'match' attribute is invalid. I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the error is probably because of you doing **!(img)**, which is not valid. It should be **not(img)**

However, in your XSLT, you are checking for whether the **img** element is a child of the **a** element. You should really be making us of the **following-sibling** axis instead.

```
<xsl:template match="a[not(following-sibling::*[1][self::img]) and not(@id)]">
```

So, **following-sibling::*[1]** matches the first following sibling of the **a** element, and then **[self::img]** checks if it is an **img** tag.

Note, if you were to do just **a[not(following-sibling::*[self::img])** then it would look for any following-sibling, not just the one that immediately follows the **a** element.